# Why is the Enhancements tab missing on my sound card?

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, pci

I am trying to enable Virtual Surround on my speakers. I followed these steps:

- Click Sounds on the control panel
- Select my speakers from the playback tab
- Click properties

At this point, there should be an enhancements tab at the top which contains the setting for Virtual Surround, it should look like this:

[image]

However, there is none, and the only related tab is one called "Sound Blaster" which contains a checkbox called "Disable Enhancements".

This is a Rocketfish 5.1 PCI Sound Card, and the drivers were installed from Windows Update. It comes with an application called "Audio Control Panel" which has some enhancements, however this doesn't contain the Virtual Surround option. Is there any way to enable this function (maybe by using Windows generic sound drivers)?

Answer (score 0):

If you found new sound control panel is not useful, just uninstall it from your windows control panel "uninstall or change a program".
Enhancement tab will be re-enabled.

Comment: I tried this out but unfortunately the tab is still missing - is it possibly because of the sound driver itself?

Comment: Yes, maybe, just find updated driver for your sound card from "view update history" and uninstall it. I don't think newer drivers really have better performance.